# How to suppress "Confirm 'set'? (y/n)" promtp for the `tmux conf 'set -g mouse on'`?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, tmux

I would lke to make these two aliases work without prompting:

```sh
alias txmon="tmux conf 'set -g mouse on'  &&  tmux conf 'set -g mouse-utf8 on'"
```

```sh
alias txmoff="tmux conf 'set -g mouse off'  &&  tmux conf 'set -g mouse-utf8 off'"
```

but when run in a tmux session, the yield this prompt in brown font at the bottom left hand-side corner:

```
Confirm 'set'? (y/n)
```

I couldn't find anything on the matter either in `man tmux` nor on the World Wlid Web ;)

Comment: well I have worked this around with some friendly suggestion to use Shift+LMB to select and Shift+MMB to paste.

Answer (score 2):

conf matches the command `confirm-before` and that is what it does - it asks for confirmation.

If you don't want it to ask, don't use that command:

```
alias txmon="tmux set -g mouse on \; set -g mouse-utf8 on"
```

Note that `mouse-utf8` was removed from tmux some years ago so you should check you still need it.

Also if you want to toggle the option you can leave out the on or off: `tmux set -g mouse`.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way perhaps to override this `confirm-before` (is it maybe configurable some how?) Just to make it pass automatically?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you don't want to be asked, don't use confirm-before, like the example I gave. If you do want to be asked then tmux needs to wait for you to answer.